# Transparant Background of a Form (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0

I have to create a Laser pointer type of cursor to show on a Powerpoint Presentation. the cursor should be a circle with opacity. I have managed to do this on Windows 7 but when i start my application on XP it shows a rectangle.

I have created a form which has a backcolor that has the same color as the transparancykey. 
By doing this it shows only the background (PNG) image of the form (which is circle with transparent background). I also use opacity on the form .

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must give `AllowTransparency=true`

Comment: I had AllowTransparency already set to true but. In windows 7 it shows precisely as i intented. In Windows XP it only shows a square instead of an ellipse. Do you have any other suggestions?